Display calendar with week numbers
I would like to display a calendar with week numbers.
Python provides a nice calendar module that can generate such a calendar, but I can’t find a way to display week numbers.
Here is an example of the command and its output:
python -m calendar --locale fr --encoding utf-8 --type text 2024

                                  2024

      janvier                   février                     mars
Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di      Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di      Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7                1  2  3  4                   1  2  3
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14       5  6  7  8  9 10 11       4  5  6  7  8  9 10
15 16 17 18 19 20 21      12 13 14 15 16 17 18      11 12 13 14 15 16 17
22 23 24 25 26 27 28      19 20 21 22 23 24 25      18 19 20 21 22 23 24
29 30 31                  26 27 28 29               25 26 27 28 29 30 31

And here is what I would like to achieve:
                                          2024

          janvier                       février                         mars
    Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di          Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di
 1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7       5            1  2  3  4        9               1  2  3
 2   8  9 10 11 12 13 14       6   5  6  7  8  9 10 11       10   4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 3  15 16 17 18 19 20 21       7  12 13 14 15 16 17 18       11  11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 4  22 23 24 25 26 27 28       8  19 20 21 22 23 24 25       12  18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 5  29 30 31                   9  26 27 28 29                13  25 26 27 28 29 30 31

Is it possible to obtain this result with the Python calendar module? If it is not directly possible, how can I extend the module to get this new feature?
I’m open to a totally different approach if it makes sense.

Documentation for the calendar module addresses producing modified calendars.

I read the doc twice and I don’t see anything about producing modified calendars. Can you provide a link?

I subclassed TextCalendar (the original is at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/calendar.py ) and modified 3 methods:

formatmonth, so that it passes the week number in addition to the
week to formatweek
formatweek now prints this week number
before the days
formatheader in order to shift the headers to
accomodate the new field


from calendar import TextCalendar, LocaleTextCalendar
from datetime import date


class WeekNumTextCalendar(TextCalendar):
    def formatweekheader(self, width):
        """
        Return a header for a week, shifted for the weeknum field.
        """
        # shift by 5 characters
        return ' '*5 + super().formatweekheader(width) 
    
    def formatweek(self, theweek, width, weeknum):
        "Prints weeknum before the days of the week"
        days = super().formatweek(theweek, width)
        return f'{weeknum:>2} | ' + days
    
    def formatmonth(self, theyear, themonth, w=0, l=0):
        """
        Return a month's calendar string (multi-line).
        Passes an additional argument weeknum to formatweek
        """
        w = max(2, w)
        l = max(1, l)
        s = self.formatmonthname(theyear, themonth, 7 * (w + 1) - 1)
        s = s.rstrip()
        s += '\n' * l
        s += self.formatweekheader(w).rstrip()
        s += '\n' * l
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(theyear, themonth):
            # week is a list of (day, weekday), where day=0 if not in the current month
            # we get the first non-zero dat of the current week
            day = next(day for (day, weekday) in week if day!=0)
            # isocalendar returns a named tuple (year, week, weekday)
            weeknum = date(theyear, themonth, day).isocalendar().week
            s += self.formatweek(week, w, weeknum).rstrip()
            s += '\n' * l
        return s
    

Sample run:
c = WeekNumTextCalendar()
c.prmonth(2024, 3)


     March 2024
     Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 9 |              1  2  3
10 |  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 | 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
12 | 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
13 | 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

In order to get localized versions, you can do:
class LocaleWeekNumCalendar(WeekNumTextCalendar, LocaleTextCalendar):
    "Localized version of WeekNumCalendar"
    pass

c = LocaleWeekNumCalendar()
c.prmonth(2024, 3)

    mars 2024
     lu ma me je ve sa di
 9 |              1  2  3
10 |  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 | 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
12 | 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
13 | 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

Note that you would still have to update formatyear in order to print calendars for a whole year.

Excellent, I didn’t know it was so easy to create a subclass. What was harder is to figure out how to update formatyear and get a localized version, but I got it working at the end. I will post my solution below. Many thanks for your answer @Thierry Lathuille.

This solution is based on Thierry Lathuille’s answer, which I have accepted.
It also generates calendars for an entire year, not just one month.
"""
Create calendars with week numbers.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78512891/3057377
"""

from calendar import TextCalendar, month_name, formatstring
from datetime import date
import locale

WEEK_OFFSET = " | "
DAY_OFFSET = " " * (len(WEEK_OFFSET) + 2)
LAST_WEEK_OFFSET = " " * (len(WEEK_OFFSET) + 22)
MONTH_OFFSET = " " * (len(WEEK_OFFSET) + 2)
YEAR_OFFSET = 7 + 4 * len(WEEK_OFFSET)


class WeekNumTextCalendar(TextCalendar):

    def formatmonthname(self, theyear, themonth, width, withyear=True):
        """
        Return a formatted month name.
        """
        s = month_name[themonth]
        if withyear:
            s = "%s %r" % (s, theyear)
        return MONTH_OFFSET + s.center(width)

    def formatweekheader(self, width):
        """
        Return a header for a week.
        """
        return DAY_OFFSET + super().formatweekheader(width)

    def formatweek(self, theweek, width, weeknum):
        "Prints weeknum before the days of the week"
        days = super().formatweek(theweek, width)
        return f"{weeknum:>2}{WEEK_OFFSET}{days}"

    def formatyear(self, theyear, w=2, l=1, c=6, m=3):  # noqa E741
        """
        Returns a year's calendar as a multi-line string.
        """
        w = max(2, w)
        l = max(1, l)  # noqa E741
        c = max(2, c)
        colwidth = (w + 1) * 7 - 1
        v = []
        a = v.append
        a(repr(theyear).center(YEAR_OFFSET + (colwidth * m + c * (m - 1))).rstrip())
        a("\n" * l)
        header = self.formatweekheader(w)
        for i, row in enumerate(self.yeardays2calendar(theyear, m)):  # i = 0,1,2,3
            # months in this row
            months = range(m * i + 1, min(m * (i + 1) + 1, 13))
            a("\n" * l)
            names = (self.formatmonthname(theyear, k, colwidth, False) for k in months)
            a(formatstring(names, colwidth, c).rstrip())
            a("\n" * l)
            headers = (header for k in months)
            a(formatstring(headers, colwidth, c).rstrip())
            a("\n" * l)
            # max number of weeks for this row
            height = max(len(cal) for cal in row)
            for j in range(height):
                weeks = []
                for cnt, cal in enumerate(row):
                    if j >= len(cal):
                        weeks.append(LAST_WEEK_OFFSET)
                        continue
                    day = cal[j][0][0] if cal[j][0][0] != 0 else 1
                    weeknum = date(theyear, months[cnt], day).isocalendar().week
                    weeks.append(self.formatweek(cal[j], w, weeknum))
                a(formatstring(weeks, colwidth, c).rstrip())
                a("\n" * l)
        return "".join(v)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "fr_CH.UTF-8")
    c = WeekNumTextCalendar()
    for _y in range(2024, 2026):
        print("\n\n\n" + " " * (33 + 2 * len(WEEK_OFFSET)) + "**************\n\n")
        c.pryear(_y)

Sample output
                                            2024

           janvier                        février                          mars
     Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di
 1 |  1  2  3  4  5  6  7       5 |           1  2  3  4       9 |              1  2  3
 2 |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14       6 |  5  6  7  8  9 10 11      10 |  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 3 | 15 16 17 18 19 20 21       7 | 12 13 14 15 16 17 18      11 | 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 4 | 22 23 24 25 26 27 28       8 | 19 20 21 22 23 24 25      12 | 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 5 | 29 30 31                   9 | 26 27 28 29               13 | 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

            avril                           mai                            juin
     Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di
14 |  1  2  3  4  5  6  7      18 |        1  2  3  4  5      22 |                 1  2
15 |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14      19 |  6  7  8  9 10 11 12      23 |  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
16 | 15 16 17 18 19 20 21      20 | 13 14 15 16 17 18 19      24 | 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 | 22 23 24 25 26 27 28      21 | 20 21 22 23 24 25 26      25 | 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
18 | 29 30                     22 | 27 28 29 30 31            26 | 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

           juillet                          août                        septembre
     Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di
27 |  1  2  3  4  5  6  7      31 |           1  2  3  4      35 |                    1
28 |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14      32 |  5  6  7  8  9 10 11      36 |  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
29 | 15 16 17 18 19 20 21      33 | 12 13 14 15 16 17 18      37 |  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
30 | 22 23 24 25 26 27 28      34 | 19 20 21 22 23 24 25      38 | 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
31 | 29 30 31                  35 | 26 27 28 29 30 31         39 | 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
                                                              40 | 30

           octobre                        novembre                       décembre
     Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di           Lu Ma Me Je Ve Sa Di
40 |     1  2  3  4  5  6      44 |              1  2  3      48 |                    1
41 |  7  8  9 10 11 12 13      45 |  4  5  6  7  8  9 10      49 |  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
42 | 14 15 16 17 18 19 20      46 | 11 12 13 14 15 16 17      50 |  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
43 | 21 22 23 24 25 26 27      47 | 18 19 20 21 22 23 24      51 | 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
44 | 28 29 30 31               48 | 25 26 27 28 29 30         52 | 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
                                                               1 | 30 31

